# max(message_id) not working properly in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to get max of message_id from mysql database and increment it by 1. and insert value in database, my problem is every time it is taking 1 and inserting it into database. message_id is not tormenting.

```
$selectmessageid = mysqli_query ($dbc,"SELECT max(message_id) from wp_fep_messages");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectmessageid)) 
            {
                $message_id = $row['message_id'];
            }

       $message_id++;
```

Comment: Why you do not use an autoincrement for message_id? So the db will do this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give it an alias, otherwise you're going to be referencing it as `$row['max(message_id)'];`

```
SELECT max(message_id) AS message_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to get it using $row[0] or use aliasing.

Try this.

```
 $selectmessageid = mysqli_query ($dbc,"SELECT max(message_id) from wp_fep_messages");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectmessageid)) 
            {
                $message_id = $row[0];
            }

       $message_id++;
```

or

```
$selectmessageid = mysqli_query ($dbc,"SELECT max(message_id) as 'message_id' from wp_fep_messages");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectmessageid)) 
            {
                $message_id = $row['message_id'];
            }

       $message_id++;
```

Comment: Why do you create an alias if you're not going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `alias` here.

Use this one:

```
$selectmessageid = mysqli_query ($dbc,"SELECT max(message_id) as maxid from wp_fep_messages");

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectmessageid)) 
            {
                $message_id = $row['maxid'];
            }

       $message_id++;
```

**Note:** Always use alias when you use mysql function in query with fields.